# Parsing the JSON Response Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I am new to Angular Java scripting and I am trying to call a web service and use the returned JSON in a Controller like below

```
   var nameBarcodePrjList = []; 
        var url = $rootScope.BaseURL + "PROJECT";
        var configPrj = {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Basic ${$scope.key}`
            }
        };
            $http.get(url, configPrj)
            .then(
            function (response) { // success async
                var nameBarcodePrjData = response.data.value;

                for (var i = 0; i < nameBarcodePrjData.length; i++) {
                    var namePrjBarcode = {
                        Name: "",
                        Barcode: ""
                    };
                    namePrjBarcode.Name = nameBarcodePrjData[i].Name;
                    namePrjBarcode.Barcode = nameBarcodePrjData[i].Barcode;
                    console.log(nameBarcodePrjData[i].Name);
                    nameBarcodePrjList.push(namePrjBarcode);
                };
                return nameBarcodePrjList;
                console.log("Success");
```

Even though the response comes back in json like below

[image]

It is not building the nameBarcodePrjList with Name and Barcode, i mean it returns null array. Am I missing something while parsing the response here?

Comment: what do you get in `console.log(nameBarcodePrjData[i].Name);` inside your `for` loop?

Comment: You can declare your ``nameBarcodePrjList`` inside ``then``, because it gets populated and returned inside ``then`` anyway.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal the debugger was not even reaching that code instead it was breaking. So I commented out everything inside function(response) it reached `console.log("Success");` I am sure I am missing something while parsing, but dont know what

Answer (score 0):

If `console.log(nameBarcodePrjData[i].Name)` works fine.

The problem should be in `nameBarcodePrjList.push(nameBarcode);` line.

nameBarcode is not defined anywhere in your code and that should be giving the error.

Thanks

Comment: nameBarcode was typo. I have corrected that in my code still doesnt work

Comment: What does console.log(nameBarcodePrjData[i].Name) line printing in console?

Comment: Your code will never reach this line `console.log("Success");` because you are returning nameBarcodePrjList in the line before that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying `return whatever;` from `success` callback, as those are `async` calls by default you can't simply use `return whatever;`.

In order to do so, you have to use `promise`. In `angular` there's `$q` service for that.

to by pass the things, what you can do is declare a var outside the `$http.get()` and try populating it inside the `success` callback so that it can get initialized, and then you can access it.

Something like :-

```
var globalDataStore = [];
$http.get(url, configPrj)
        .then(
        function (response) {
            globalDataStore = response.data.value;
            workWithTheGlobalDataStore();
        });
 function workWithTheGlobalDataStore(){
     var firstItem = globalDataStore.length > 0 ? globalDataStore[0] : '';
     console.log('firstItem : ', firstItem);
 }
```